# Could not load compiled classes for settings file

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I try to modify one of my old projects but now it is throwing some error and I can't figure out why is this throwing this error. Please help!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'D:\Workspace\projects\oldproject\android\settings.gradle' from cache.
> settings_3552tbte83k26vrb8052nbmuc

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Update**

`setting.gradle` file

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear gradle cache

The `<home directory>/.gradle/caches` directory holds the Gradle build cache you can delete it.

you can refer to this [article](https://newbedev.com/how-to-clear-gradle-cache) to show how to Gradle build cache

Comment: can you please help a little bit how to do that ?

Comment: can't send message on that. Please mention all steps here. Thanks

Comment: I deleted the cache. but no effect

Comment: can you share project/android/settings.gradle file please